# Make sure the ACL and firewall rule is correctly configured in the Azure Data Lake Store account

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm coping CSV files from Azure blob to Azure Data Lake using Azure data factory using Copy data tool.
I'm following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool

Fron Copy data tool my source configuration and test connection successed. However, the destination connection (that is Data lake) is creating problem.

I'm getting error : Make sure the ACL and firewall rule is correctly configured in the Azure Data Lake Store account.

I followed this link for Fairwall setting:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data (Set IP address range for data access)

Enabled fairwall and Allow access to Azure service "ON"

Still, I'm getting same error. Could any one please suggest. How to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Get your *Managed Identity Application ID* from *Azure Data Factory properties*.

Go to Azure Data Lake Storage and navigate to `Data Explorer -> Access -> Add` and then provide the ID in the 'Select User or group' field.
It will identify your Azure Data Factory instance/resource and then provide ACLs(R/W/X) as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Except the firewall setting, please also be sure that your account has necessary permission on the target ADLS account. Please refer to this doc for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store#linked-service-properties

Answer (score 0):

Your account and application ADF need to have permission to work on ADLS. Also, see did you gave permission to children folders as well.